# Array adapter and listview issues after launching Intent Service

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a list view being populated by my array adapter. Now everything works fine until i click on a row which launches an async task.

My async task is supposed to download some image urls and launch an intent service in it's onPostExecute to download the images and store them on the SDcard.

All this works fine but once i hit back and relaunch the fragment mid the network operations, my listview is empty and remains empty until the intent service is done. What could be the problem here? I have an AsyncTask handling the downloads in the intent service so why does the service "block" the main thread?

Comment: maybe the service does some deep work.. you know that services run on the main thread right?

Comment: Yeah I know but there's an Async task in the intent service handling the downloads. Or am I not getting something here?

Comment: As far as I know your fragment will not wait for the intent service. Can you post your fragment code you use to populate the listview

Comment: Added the whole fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading around i finally found out what i was doing wrong, mainly due to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491049/start-async-task-from-onhandleintent) here and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935531/problems-in-calling-asynctask-from-intentservice). `onHandleIntent` runs on a worker thread so there really was no need for me to create an `Async task` in the intent service in the first place. So i replaced my Async task in the intent service with a method and called that method in `onHandleIntent` and that solved my problem.