# Android - Separate thread still blocks UI

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a problem with IntentService and cannot find solution. I have an UploadService class that extends IntentService.

```
public class UploadService extends IntentService {

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    sendItems();
}
```

sendItems() - method used to send files to Parse. It modifies some files if needed (operates on external storage), then communication occurrs.

What are possible causes of UI freeze?

Comment: whats in sendItems(); method?

Comment: `onHandleIntent()` is already called on a background thread. Please **do not create yet another thread** here. Your problem with the main application thread lies elsewhere. Use Traceview and/or `StrictMode` to try to identify where you are doing too much work on the main application thread.

Comment: May be any other part of code from thread is working on UI thread.

Comment: Had a similar issue and the problem was creating the new thread in the onHandleIntent. onHandleIntent runs on a separate thread so you can directly handle your network operations in it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705584/array-adapter-and-listview-issues-after-launching-intent-service

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, it's an overkill.

sendItems() is a method that invokes file upload. It modifies some files if needed and then uploads them to Parse db.

I will edit my question to match current problem: Does file modification conflict with UI thread?